# Rails, running becomes after a find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to change the class of each result returned in an active record query. I would like to to happen whenever any query is run and results are returned. Unfortunately I cannot use STI to accomplish this. For example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_find :becomes_a_subclass

   def becomes_a_subclass
      becomes [Bar, Baz, Raz].sample
   end

end

class Bar < Foo ; end
class Baz < Foo ; end
class Raz < Foo ; end
```

I would expect the following to return the given result:

```
=> Foo.all
[#<Bar id: 1>, #<Baz id: 2>, #<Bar id: 3>, #<Raz id: 4>]
```

Comment: Whatever you want, please make it more clear, I have **no** clue what you are asking.

Comment: My example ressult was not posted. please see above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to implement the [`discriminate_class_for_record(record)`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/discriminate_class_for_record) class method on `Foo`. This should return the subclass for the record. Example implementation:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.discriminate_class_for_record(record)
    if record['foobar']
      [Bar, Baz, Raz].sample
    else
      super
    end
  end

end

class Bar < Foo ; end
class Baz < Foo ; end
class Raz < Foo ; end
```